# Performing several hundred raster multiplications

Tags: r, graphics, geospatial

I have several hundred "A" rasters, numbered from `001_A.tif` to `100_A.tif`.

I also have several hundred "B" rasters, numbered from `001_B.tif` to `100_B.tif`.

I want to multiply them like this:

```
001_A * 001_B = 001_result
002_A * 002_B = 002_result
003_A * 003_B = 003_result
.
.
.
```

I have a loop in R which works fine, but it is relatively slow:

```
library(raster)

A_Files <- list.files(pattern="A.tif") # files A
All_A <- unique(A_Files)

B_Files <- list.files(pattern="B") # files B
All_B <- unique(B_Files)

for (i in 1:100) {
  A.i <- All_A[i]
  B.i <- All_B[i]

  Raster_A.i <- raster(A.i) # create rasters from files A
  Raster_B.i <- raster(B.i) # create rasters from files B

  Result.i <- (Raster_A.i * Raster_B.i) # multiplying A by B

  writeRaster(Result.i, paste(A.i, "_result.tif", sep = ""), datatype='FLT4S',
 overwrite=TRUE) # write results in .tif format with the name "001_A_result.tif"
    }
```

Is there a way to speed it up?

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Answer (score 1):

### Rasters

Rasters are highly memory intensive in R's already fragile memory space. However, one does not necessarily need to read a raster into memory each time. In fact, it is highly frowned upon to read in a raster in that way as it just eats up so much memory and is computationally intensive.

### `stack()`'s beauty

It's much better to make a stack of rasters as it does not load them into memory, but opens their file location.

```
library(raster)

A_Files <- list.files(pattern="A.tif") # files A
All_A <- stack(unique(A_Files))

B_Files <- list.files(pattern="B") # files B
All_B <- stack(unique(B_Files))
```

Notice, all of the elements are now in a "vectorized" form.

### `overlay()` to calculate

From here, we can use `overlay()` to perform a calculation. Note, since the number of layers is equivalent between (ALL_A) and (ALL_B) we do not need to worry about an element being repeated.

```
x <- overlay(All_A, All_B, fun=function(x,y) x*y )
```

### Export

The only downside to this approach is you will have to go through a loop to export the answers:

```
out <- unstack(x)
outputnames <- paste0(seq_along(out), "_result.tif")
for(i in seq_along(out)){ writeRaster(out[[i]], file=outputnames[i]) }
```

## References

For multiplying stacks see:

- [overlay](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/raster/docs/overlay)
- [calc](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/raster/docs/calc)

For more information on stacks (see bricks as well)

- [stack](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/raster/docs/stack)
- [brick](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/raster/docs/brick)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the overlay part is not working. Or maybe it is working, but it takes so long that I interrupted it manually. I chcecked it by the system.time function. Doesn't it multiply each raster A with each raster B, instead of multiplying only two matching rasters?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I saved some time using the `lapply` or the `map` function.

Here is the code with `lapply`:

```
require(raster) # raster package

setwd("C:/Rasters") # set working directory

A_Files <- list.files(pattern="A.tif") # files A
All_A <- stack(unique(A_Files)) # stacking As

B_Files <- list.files(pattern="B") # files B
All_B <- stack(unique(B_Files)) # stacking Bs

As <- lapply(All_A, raster) # rasters from A

Bs <- lapply(All_B, raster) # rasters from B

# multiplying A*B:
Multiply_A_B <- lapply(seq_along(As), FUN = function(i) As[[i]] * Bs[[i]])

# saving results as "_result.tif"
lapply(seq_along(Multiply_A_B), function(x) {
    writeRaster(Multiply_A_B[[x]],
    paste(All_A[x], "_result.tif", sep = ""),
      datatype = 'FLT4S', overwrite = TRUE)
})
```

Code with the `map` function:

```
# multiplying A*B:
Multiply <- Map("*", As, Bs)
# the rest is the same as with the lapply example above
```

The operation took 210 seconds with `for` loop, while with the `lapply` it took 190 seconds and with `map` it took 185 seconds.